# How to write a list to a text file in the correct format

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've got this piece of code that I want to write the output to a text file but with the correct format i.e. no brackets, single quotes so it appears as a formatted list.

This is the code:

```
file = open("env5.txt", "w");
for key in os.environ.keys():
  env = os.environ[key];
  key1 = key;
  list = str([key, env]).replace("'","").replace('[]', '');
  list2 = list[1:-1];
  print(list2);
  file.writelines(list2);
```

file.close();

This is the original code:

```
for key in os.environ.keys():
print(key, os.environ[key]);
```

Many thanks

Comment: Can you include an example of an input and a desired output?

Comment: +1 on desired output.

Answer (score 2):

```
with open("env5.txt", "w") as fout:
    for k, v in os.environ.items():
        print(k, v, file=fout)
```